# ¿Cómo evitar los elementos duplicados productos de un JOIN?

Tags: oracle, plsql

no logro encontrar la forma.

Tengo la tabla cabeceras que trae 1 solo registro por cada comprobante y sobre la cual hago una suma entre columnas, a la vez, tengo la tabla detalles donde hay desde 1 a 10 en el campo linea , y son cada linea del comprobante . Necesito listar la tabla cabeceras y en el resultado de la consulta agregar la sumatoria de todas las lineas de cada comprobante ( tabla detalles ) . He logrado algo parecido pero me lista el campo comprobante_id tantas veces como lineas ... es oracle 8

```html
SELECT b.comprobante_ID,a.SUBTOTAL AS SUB , a.IVA AS IVA,SUBTOTAL+iva AS TOTAL1, a.TOTAL AS TOTAL2, ((a.SUBTOTAL+iva)-(a.TOTAL)) AS DIFERENCIA, SUM(b.IMPORTE)AS TOTAL3  
FROM CABECERAS a, DETALLES b  
WHERE a.punto=135 
AND a.comprobante_ID=b.comprobante_ID
AND FEC_EMISION=TO_DATE('01/10/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')GROUP BY b.comprobante_ID,b.IMPORTE,a.SUBTOTAL, a.iva,a.TOTAL, b.importe
```

La consulta funciona pero necesito que se agrupe en una sola linea por cada b.comprobante_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que habrás notado es que al tener más registros de `DETALLE` por `Comprobate_ID` se repiten las filas de `CABECERA` produciendo que las sumatorias den resultados inconsistentes. Una solución, si de `DETALLE` solo necesitas obtener un total, es agrupar por `Comprobate_ID` sumar `IMPORTE` y incorporar esto como subconsulta. Algo así:

```
SELECT  a.comprobante_ID,
    a.SUBTOTAL          AS SUB, 
    a.IVA               AS IVA,
    a.SUBTOTAL+a.iva    AS TOTAL1, 
    a.TOTAL             AS TOTAL2, 
    ((a.SUBTOTAL+a.iva)-(a.TOTAL))  AS DIFERENCIA, 
    b.TOTAL3
    FROM CABECERAS a 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT comprobante_ID, 
            SUM(IMPORTE) AS TOTAL3  
            FROM DETALLES 
            GROUP BY comprobante_ID
        )  b  
        ON a.comprobante_ID=b.comprobante_ID
    WHERE   a.punto=135 
        AND a.FEC_EMISION=TO_DATE('01/10/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

**Comentario**: Evita la sintaxis de los `JOIN` implíctos, está deprecada hace muchos años y algunos motores ya no la soportan.

En caso que estuvieras obligado a usar la sintaxis implícita, por ejemplo en el caso de la versión 8i (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24576419/6836377) esta sería la consulta:

```
SELECT  a.comprobante_ID,
    a.SUBTOTAL          AS SUB, 
    a.IVA               AS IVA,
    a.SUBTOTAL+a.iva    AS TOTAL1, 
    a.TOTAL             AS TOTAL2, 
    ((a.SUBTOTAL+a.iva)-(a.TOTAL))  AS DIFERENCIA, 
    b.TOTAL3
    FROM CABECERAS a, 
        (SELECT comprobante_ID, 
            SUM(IMPORTE) AS TOTAL3  
            FROM DETALLES 
            GROUP BY comprobante_ID
        )  b  
    WHERE   a.punto=135 
    AND a.comprobante_ID=b.comprobante_ID
        AND a.FEC_EMISION=TO_DATE('01/10/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: por desgracia oracle si y la siguen enseñando para esa DB :(

Comment: @gbianchi, si, es un problema. Estaría bueno hacer una pregunta para documentar que motores lo soportan y cuales no..

Comment: o mejor una pregunta sobre joins.. pero da mas para un post en un blog que una pregunta.. es una buena idea.. :)

Comment: Hola gracias ! pero parece algo anda mal .. no jala , sale : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Me señala el error en el INNER

Comment: @look68, no veo nada particularmente raro. Lo he probado con tablas `dummy` y al menos no me dá error de sintaxis: https://rextester.com/AVC86414

Comment: que raro ... me da textual ese error , y se queda resaltando la sentencia INNER ...

Comment: sera que estoy en oracle 8 ?

Comment: Gracioso, pero parece que sí, 8i no soportaría JOIN explícitos, ahora edito mi respuesta